# RMTP Tunneling - how different it is from HTTP request?

Tags: apache-flex, http, rtmp, weborb

While using RTMP if the request is tunneled through HTTP, how different it is from a HTTP request?

What would be the performance implications of tunneling while using RTMP?

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of RTMP streams over the casual HTTP based progressive downloading is far too realistic to ignore

You can serve Flash Video over the Internet using RTMP, a special protocol for real-time server applications ranging from instant messaging to collaborative data sharing to video streaming. Whereas HTTP-delivered Flash Video is referred to as progressive download video, RTMP-delivered Flash Video is called streaming video. However, because the term streaming is so often misused, I prefer the term real-time streaming video.

One of the benefits of RTMP delivery for the viewer is near-instantaneous playback of video, provided the Flash Video file is encoded with a bitrate appropriate to the viewer's connection speed. Real-time streaming video can also be seeked to any point in the content. This feature is particularly advantageous for long-duration content because the viewer doesn't have to wait for the video file to load before jumping ahead, as is the case for HTTP-delivered video.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/video/ps11488/ps11791/ps11802/white_paper_c11-675935.html